# Spring Resttemplate login fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

after an update to spring-4.1.6 i'am not able to login to my rest services any more.

I looked on different sides, but couldn't solve the problem... so i ask for help.

Here is my my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
   version="2.5"> 

   <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Security Stuff -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="ROLE_USER" />

        <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
            authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler" />
        <logout />
        <csrf disabled="false"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.test.webservice.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler"
        class="com.test.webservice.security.RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:bean id="myFailureHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="temporary" password="temporary" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Here is a snippet how i try to call the login:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> form = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
form.add("j_username", username);
form.add("j_password", password);
return restTemplate.postForLocation(serverUri + "j_spring_security_check", form);
```

Here is the controller:

```
@RestController
public class JustAServiceController {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JustAServiceController.class);

    @Autowired
    private JustAService justAService;

    @RequestMapping(value = RestURIConstants.JUSTASERVICE_EXCEPTION, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody MyFirstClassDTO throwException() throws DummyException{
        throw new DummyException("fasdfasdf", 1);
    }
```

And here the exception i receive:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at com.test.webservice.client.TestResponseErrorHandler.handleError(TestResponseErrorHandler.java:21)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForLocation(RestTemplate.java:305)
    at com.test.webservice.client.AbstractServiceWrapper.login(AbstractServiceWrapper.java:49)
    at com.testexample.webService.JustAServiceControllerTest.initWrapper(JustAServiceControllerTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

And if i disable CSRF then i get this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at com.mleitner.lara.webservice.client.LaraResponseErrorHandler.handleError(LaraResponseErrorHandler.java:21)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForLocation(RestTemplate.java:305)
    at com.mleitner.lara.webservice.client.AbstractServiceWrapper.login(AbstractServiceWrapper.java:49)
    at com.mleitner.laraexample.webService.JustAServiceControllerTest.initWrapper(JustAServiceControllerTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I'am sure this source already worked... but i did the last remote tests more than 6 months ago... so i'am not sure that the spring lib update was the only relevant change. Thanks in advance for your help.

KR

Comment: Did you really only upgrade Spring or was there also a Spring Security upgrade done. You are using Spring 4 which has CSFR enabled by default, either provide the header or disable XSFR.

Comment: No, i upgraded also Spring Security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have upgraded Spring Security to 4.x as well (evidenced by `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd`).  Unfortunately, Spring Security 4.x is not a drop-in replacement for 3.x.  You will need to review the [Official Migration Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) for configuration elements that need to be tweaked.  However, some of the ones that stand out from your post are:

1. CSRF protection [is enabled by default](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-csrf).  If you are not injecting CSRF tokens in your HTML forms, you will need to switch it off.
2. Default login URL [has changed from `j_spring_security_check` to `login`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login).  Since your client code posts to `j_spring_security_check`, it will encounter a `404` error since that URL does not exist by default.  You will have to change that to `login`.
3. Login form username parameter [has changed from `j_username` to `username`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login).  You will have to change your client code for this.
4. Similarly, login form password parameter [has changed from `j_password` to `password`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-form-login).  You will have to change your client code for this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Without CSRF tokens it works. I access my server only by JSON by using RestTemplate. Should i activate CSRF and if yes, is it possible by using RestTemplate?

Comment: If you use HTTP `POST` with your `RestTemplate`, it may be a good idea to have CSRF protection enabled.  The way it will work is that you will return a strong, random token as a call to `login`.  The client will cache this (say, in an in-memory variable) and replay it in an HTTP header with every subsequent request.  The server would look for the token in the said header for every subsequent request, reject those requests that do not have the token and validate the token for those that have it.  As long as the communication is over HTTPs, the token cannot be grabbed midway.